# Trying to identify self-published story about fans of a children's book series

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, novella

I'm trying to track down a self-published story or novella I read online roughly a decade ago, possibly on someone's Livejournal.

It was written in the form of a series of emails or newsgroup posts exchanged by adult fans of an series of British children's fantasy novels (a bit like Narnia, but more of an obscure cult thing). The author of these novels was a mysterious eccentric whose work had gradually descended into gibberish, possibly masking some hidden, occult significance.
The fans' efforts to solve the mystery brought them together in real life, but the tone darkened as the story went on.

Does this ring a bell with anyone?

Comment: It's not a close match, but it sounds a lot in overall concept like [House of Leaves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Leaves).  A lot of the actual details are different, however.

Comment: Definitely not that, but thanks—I haven't read House of Leaves, but going by the synopsis it may well have influenced the story I'm thinking of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds a lot like [The Northern Caves](https://archiveofourown.org/works/3659997/chapters/8088522) (link to story) by nostalgebraist (don't know their real name). It's [described](https://archiveofourown.org/works/3659997/chapters/8088522) by the author as "about a cult fantasy author and his bizarre, seemingly unreadable final book.  It’s about his fans, and their struggle to make sense of that book.  It’s about moral philosophy, meeting your heroes, crushing senses of duty, and steampunk rabbit fanfic. And it’s told, in part, through mocked-up forum threads from a fictitious mid-2000s fan site."

The name of the fictional series is Chesscourt. And the story (nostalgebraist's, that is) does indeed take on a darker tone as it progresses. It differs from the OP's description in that it's not the series as a whole, but the final book specifically (entitled The Northern Caves), that descends into gibberish, and it's that book that the fans try to make sense of.

Comment: This is it!! Thank you so much.

Comment: @JakeWilson - could you please accept the answer?